# Post to Facebook page using fb access-token in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there any way to publish a post on facebook without user login by using page/app access-token?. is it possible to do this with javascript with access-token.

Comment: It is theoretically possible - but you should __never_ expose a page access token in publicly available client-side code, where everyone could steal it from and then use it to perform other actions in the name of your page.

Comment: Hi, Have you any idea how to do it. i have done lot R&D. bu i could not find a solutions

Comment: Embed the JS SDK, use FB.api to make the request, and supply your page access token as additional parameter ...